# How to preserve request data Laravel Lumen through the lifetime of a request?

Tags: php, laravel, httprequest, lumen

I am using Lumen to build an API and I am trying to figure out what the best way is to keep data in memory for the entire duration of a request.  The idea is to avoid writing to a database or using something like `Redis` or `Memcached`.  So, basically, I want to create a global variable that I can manipulate along the way until the http action is complete and then it can disappear from memory.

For example, if I send a `POST` request with a body to my `/api/v1/postme` route, I want to accept the POST request and make another call out to another service to retrieve some data.  I want to take that data and merge it with the original data from the `POST` request.  I want to then take that newly merged data and send it as the response after some more translations.

I have read in some posts online that one can use the app config variables in the `.env` file as a temporary store of data within memory, but I was wondering if there was a different or possibly better way to accomplish this.

I read through the Laravel/Lumen documentation and it seems that I could be writing to the Lumen cache but I think that would result in making a database connection, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: if you mean for the lifetime of php, you can simply pass variables accross classes, or you can as well set it in Cache facade.

Comment: and you can as well access the \request() helper, which will contain the data i bet

Comment: @emad, interesting, I would like to try to use your idea of passing variables across classes.  How would I access the HTTP data in a Model?

Answer (score 2):

You can have it like so

```php
# Store it in request, for that run
request()->request->add(['your_param'=>'yourvalue']);

# Then access it from anywhere using
request()->get('your_param');
```

That's a pretty simple approach

Comment: can this be accessed within Models?  I am assuming that this is only accessible within the controllers at this point.  The idea is that I want to store this information globally for the app.

Comment: yes by using `request` helper, `\request()->get('your_param');` from anywhere, only if it's added somewhere before the model code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the config module of lumen follow this.

When request arrives, hits myfunc

controller.php

```
    public function myfunc(Request $request){
        app('config')->set('someuniquekey', $request);
        // call some other api
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(..);
        $response = $client->post(..);


        //retrive the value stored in config
        $request= config('someuniquekey');

        //merge $request and $response


        //This can be accessed in class method/ helper function too
        $this->func2();
        func3();
    }

    private function func2(){
        $request= config('someuniquekey'); // WORKS
    }
```

helpers.php

```
    function func3(){
        $request= config('someuniquekey'); // WORKS
    }
```